# Angular validation messages appears after reset() form

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I try to get the form to be clear without the validation error messages after calling `reset()`.

my form looks clean on load, and that is expected:
[image: form as when the page loaded, no validation errors]
however, if the user pressed the register button, and there was an error, I trigger the `form.reset()` method. I expect the form to look like the above picture, since the touch, pristine, dirty props are all as when the form is initially loaded.
but instead, it clears the values, but shows me the validation error.
[image: form with validation errors]
Can anyone help me please get it to the initial state, a clear form without the validation errors shows up?
This is a reactive form. let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you are using Angular Materials.
If so ,you must reset FormGroupDirective too,only resetting the FormGroup is not enough.

```
private registerForm(fData: any,formDirective: FormGroupDirective): void {
    formDirective.resetForm();
    this.RegForm.reset();
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="RegForm" #formDirective="ngForm" 
   (ngSubmit)="registerForm(RegForm,formDirective)">
```

Comment: Thanks !! that worked. I wasn't aware of the extra step if using angular meterial

Comment: If you want to avoid passing the directive as an argument, you can use `@ViewChild('myFormDirective') myFormDirective: FormGroupDirective;` combined with `<form #myFormDirective="ngForm"> ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
static resetForm(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    let control: AbstractControl = null;
    formGroup.reset();
    formGroup.markAsUntouched();
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach((name) => {
      control = formGroup.controls[name];
      control.setErrors(null);
    });
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like this?

```
// Reactive Form

constructor(private _builder:FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
}

createForm() {
    this.form = this._builder.group({
        key: this.value,
    });
}

// Option 1
resetForm() {
    this.form.reset();
}

// Option 2 - create form again
resetForm() {
    this.createForm()
}

// Template Form

---- HTML ----
<form #myForm="ngForm"></form>

---- TS ----
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm;

resetForm() {
   if (this.myForm) {
      this.myForm.reset();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mishal. The first answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `.markAsPristine()` of your form to reset validation:

```
this.RegForm.reset();
this.RegForm.markAsPristine();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Global ErrorStateMatcher**

With this method you won't have to reset the Form for each component. It goes throughout your application.

**1- Create a file and name it something like `default-error-state.matcher.ts` with this code in it:**

```
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';

export class DefaultErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
    isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched));
    }
}
```

**2- In `app.module.ts` provide it in the **provider** section**

```
// import the files
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
import { DefaultErrorStateMatcher } from './default-error-state.matcher';
```

Then

```
providers: [
  { provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: DefaultErrorStateMatcher }
],
```

**DONE**